# How can we handle api response in both platform in ios and android in kotlin mutlplatform?

Tags: swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

Hey I am new in the world of Kotlin Multiplatform mobile. I have experience in development of android field. I am trying to connect **Android application** and **Ios application**. I searched and see [Ktor](https://ktor.io/docs/http-client-multiplatform.html) is the way to fetch data from server. In android we use [Kotlin Sealed Classes for Handling API Responses](https://medium.com/@_pundirAbhishek/kotlin-sealed-classes-for-handling-api-responses-30d1cb256e1b) example in your application and in ios side team use [Understanding Swift closures and asynchronous request functions](https://medium.nextlevelswift.com/understanding-swift-closures-and-asynchronous-request-functions-2dd7a55cd5a6) similar to these. I am little bit confused, How can I use this way in common module to use both platform because both platform have **Interceptor** and many more things. Do I need to write everything from scratch? or Is there any way we can use existing way. My both platforms application is huge project. I don't won't to replace the code. I want to start new api call throught KMM using Ktor. Any suggestion or project would be helpful for me. Thanks

Comment: For any suspend function, an async styled function generated in iOS framework out of the box.

Comment: Could you please describe a concrete problem in the network layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to write anything from scratch. Basically you will need a separate Network Layer which will be in shared module. It will mainly consists of your request/response models and api call stuff. Here only you can define a sealed class which will provide you if the api is success or failure in your api callback and based on that you can handle your response.
You can refer to this [amazing sample](https://github.com/SimformSolutionsPvtLtd/Kotlin-multiplatform-sample) for your usecase. You can also refer to this [blog](https://proandroiddev.com/clean-architecture-example-with-kotlin-multiplatform-c361bb283fd0) for in depth understanding.

Comment: thanks a million it helps me a lot. I got the idea how to handle everything.

Comment: I want to know. In my android I am using some interceptor and authenticator through [retrofit](https://medium.com/knowing-android/headers-interceptors-and-authenticators-with-retrofit-1a00fed0d5eb). How can I use this in KMM

Comment: Good to hear it helped you. I am not sure about interceptor but I have used Authenticator with the help of this :- https://ktor.io/docs/auth.html

Comment: can i get the example ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use old `Android Code` into `Kotlin-Multiplatofrm Project` you need to do some steps

`First Step :` you should separate your code into business layer and presentation layer you can know about it by reading clean architecture Android

`Second Step :` we will put business layer into Shared Module then we will put presentation layer into ANDROID APP

`Third Step :` you should replace Retrofit Code with Ktor Code

`Fourth Step :` You should replace Room Code with SqlDlight Code

`fifth Step :` You Should Write your view in presentation layer with Compose not Xml

then application will be ready to use his business logic into ios

`sixth Step :` then you can write your swift code into IOS APP

you can look at this code this is not complete code but it will make it clear to you haw you can use
[my Kmm Repo at Github](https://github.com/ashrafdawoud/EncryptionAppKmm)

note :

`Presentation layer` contain view , viewmodel and any Platform dependent tools like workmanger

`business layer` contain network and caching code like KTOR , SQLDELIGHT and any logic that may be shared between Android and Ios

Comment: I know this all about I am talking about network layer

Comment: You Can Check GitHub Repo in above Answer And i am sure you will find your answer